# Add image to the page in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

[The Error is shown as given](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGpFm.png)I wrote the python codes to add image to the page but it displays as error.

```
photoforside = Image.open('F:\project\ShopManagement\images\psettinground.jpg')
photoforside = photoforside.resize((200, 100))
photo1in = ImageTk.PhotoImage(photoforside)
img_photo = Label(first_frame, image=photo1in, bg="#d4d9cd")
img_photo.place(x=770, y=5, width=200, height=228)
```

Comment: Would you mind posing the error you got as well?

Comment: The error is shown as 'Tcl Error'

Comment: Would you mind posting the whole error as well, not just what the error is? For example:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    print(foo)
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined

Comment: That error typically indicates that you've called `Tk()` more than once.  Each call creates an entirely separate GUI environment; an image created in one environment simply cannot be used by a widget in a different environment.  Use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Steps −

1. Import the required libraries and create an instance of tkinter frame.
2. Set the size of the frame using `.geometry` method.
3. Create a frame and specify its height and width. ...
4. Open an image using `ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("image"))`
5. Create a label object inside the frame and pass the image inside the label.

Comment: The OP seems to be doing this already...